Understanding StimulusJS connect() vs initialize() in context of turbo/hotwire
The Stimulus handbook describes the difference between connect/initialize as:
initialize(): Invoked only once, when the controller is first instantiated

connect(): Invoked anytime the controller is connected to the DOM

I created a new rails app with a homes scaffold just to make it easy on myself. I'm going to ignore a lot of rails conventions and just clear out some things for the purpose of demonstrating what my question is actually asking:
Change homes/index.html.erb to:
<div id="container">
  <div id="hello" data-controller="hello">Hello!</div>
</div>

<div data-controller="remove">
  <button data-action="click->remove#addHello">Add</button>
  <button data-action="click->remove#removeHello">Remove</button>
</div>

just to log when the initialize/connect is happening, i created hello_controller.js:
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  initialize() {
    console.log('i have been initialized');
  }
  connect() {
    console.log('i have been connected');
  }
}

and for adding/removing the controller from the dom I have remove_controller.js:
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

// Connects to data-controller="remove"
export default class extends Controller {
  removeHello() {
    const element = document.getElementById('hello');
    this.elementInMemory = element;
    element.remove();
  }

  addHello() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(this.elementInMemory);
  }
}

Everything works as expected. Every time i add the stimulus controller to the dom, it console.logs "i have been connected", but it ONLY console.logs "i have been initialized" on the initial page load. I have no issues with this, it works as expected. Let's try something different.
Changing homes/index.html.erb to:
<%= turbo_frame_tag "container" do %>
  <div id="hello" data-controller="hello">Hello!</div>
  <%= link_to "Click me", home_path(id: "1") %>
<% end %>

and changed show.html.erb
<%= turbo_frame_tag "container" do%>
  <div>World</div>
  <%= link_to "Go back", homes_path %>
<% end %>

and just to prevent an error, in HomesController removed this line:
before_action :set_home, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
You can also delete remove_controller.js if you want, it doesnt matter since it isn't doing anything.
Now the turbo frame is effectively adding/removing the controller from the dom, even though it's using turboframes instead of JS. But this is the part that's confusing to me, because now it's calling BOTH initialize and connect every time the controller is added/removed from the dom. I would think it would have the same behavior where initialize is only called once and only connect is called
ok, fine. let's try with turbo streams instead. I think of turbo streams being a bit more like JS in terms of it having append/remove/etc. actions, so maybe this will have a different behavior.
so for that, I'm going to change index.html.erb to:
<%= tag.div id: "container" do %>
  <%= render "form" %>
<% end %>

and i changed _form.html.erb to:
<div id="hello" data-controller="hello">Hello!</div>

<%= button_to "Click me", homes_path %>

in the homes controller i just changed create action to:
def create
end

and finally, create.turbo_stream.erb:
<%= turbo_stream.update "container" do %>
  <%= render "homes/form" %>
<% end %>

And of course, the same result I get from turbo frames adding/removing the controller from the dom. Each time it gets added/removed it console.logs both the initialize and connect functions.
tl;dr it seems like the controllers are initialized every time they are added/removed to the dom by turbo, but they are not initialized when they add added/removed to the dom by Stimulus/Vanilla JS.
Can anyone explain why this is? It took me wayyyy too long to realize how this works, and the documentation here doesn't seem to address this nuance

You're adding the same element from this.elementInMemory, controller for that element is already initialized, so only connect is called when you click Add.
When you do it with turbo stream/frame you're adding html and a new controller always has to be initialized again.
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

// Connects to data-controller="remove"
export default class extends Controller {
  removeHello() {
    const element = document.getElementById('hello');
    this.elementInMemory = element;
    element.remove();
  }

  addHello() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    // you could clone the element, which means a new controller
    // has to be initialized for the new element
    container.appendChild(this.elementInMemory.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

or like this
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="remove"
export default class extends Controller {
  removeHello() {
    const element = document.getElementById('hello');
    this.elementInMemory = element.outerHTML;
    element.remove();
  }

  addHello() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", this.elementInMemory);
  }
}

